# Excel, when I click a row number, far left (example row 3) I want the information in show in formula bar

Tags: excel

Excel, when I click a row number, far left (example row 3) I want the information in cell B3, C3, D3 to display in the formula box. I want it to do this for 50 rows. Can this be done without using VB editor?

Comment: Not sure you can easily do it even *with* VBA...

Comment: VB editor is not friendly with mobile devices